# How to create user defined database from user Interface in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, database-design, multiple-columns

I am creating web application ,which is developed on Asp.net MVC, Entity Frame work and Sql Server. My requirement is something different.

Let's Suppose I have table `User` which have fix column names like
`(Id,Email, Name,Age,Gender)` and this user table exists in Sql Server database.

I want to give the convenient way to add column from the user GUI to a End User.

By which suppose he feel requirement to add column name "MartialStatus" or "Weight" etc. so how can I add column from the GUI and it will map in my sql Database.

Comment: Have you considered using an XML column that can be filled with whatever properties each individual user likes? Having the application constantly add columns to a table breaks down once you have a dozen users put "Married", "Is Married", "Martial Status", "Marital Status", "Am I Married?"...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response . As Like the Zoho CRM does . If you go through the Zoho CRM and Register yourself as a User . Now Suppose If You want to add Lead then in that Case you can add your own defined fields as well.Which will only reflect to me at the time of CRUD Operation.

Comment: Allowing users to add a column does not sound like a good idea. Who are these users?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to design a database for User Defined Fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106335/how-to-design-a-database-for-user-defined-fields)