# managing (electrical) components

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I was searching for an application to manage (electrical) components that complies with the following criteria:
 - open source
 - has a purchase-history
 - allows filtering for type-specific attributes (abstract example: two categories **A**, **B** exist; following attributes belong to them: A.**a**, B.**b**, A.c, B.c; when choosing one category it should be possible to filter for those category specific attributes **a** or **b**)
 - must: linux, optional platform-independant

Here is an extraordinary example: http://uk.farnell.com/
And with a sample-search: [filters applied](http://uk.farnell.com/w/c/passive-components/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/smd-ceramic-multilayer-mlcc-capacitors?ceramic-capacitor-case=0603-1608-metric-|0805-2012-metric-)

I didn't find a program that meets the criteria and so tried to build a webapplication myself.The problems arose when trying to find a database-layout.

Here some thoughts:
-> use a table for each category, subcategory, sub-subcategory, ...
-> the most specific subcategory for a part has a reference to this part (that is in a part table)

I could not figure out if/how it is possible then to dynamically add new categories without changing all the SQL queries.
My idea was then to have a name-schema that allows me to write some code that analyzes those names and creates the query on the fly but that feels quite hacky.

Maybe someone has a reference to a database example or some tips?
(further information can be found in the edit-history, i deleted it because it blows up the post too much)

Comment: This is very off-topic.  It is either a request for software or it is a question so broad that answers would be book-length.  (Also, a quick google search shows that there are readily available starting points. E.g.: https://partkeepr.org/)

Comment: And if this is exclusively the question "how do I store attributes in a database?", then it is a duplicate.  See [How to design a database for User Defined Fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106335/how-to-design-a-database-for-user-defined-fields)

Comment: first of all sorry for being offtopic - would it be the best to delete the question? thanks for your answers anyway! partkeepr has the huge problem, that it can't search for a parameter of a specific category (e.g. category mosfet, current > 5A) or list by parameter in a specific category. furthermore parameters must be added again for a new part but in my point of view the parameters should be already defined for a specific category.
the question for me is now if it would be easier to change the project or start something new. i would be satisfied with a simpler graphical representation too

Comment: I'm not sure on delete etiquette.  You may want to check the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  W/r/t PartKeepr, I think it is meant to pull part information from Octopart.

Comment: thanks for your help again
your link above was quite helpful! trying not to be rude I would be very thankful if you could provide search terms/hints what to look for by trying to create a database-layout.
Then only methods I can think of:
a) one table that contains all possible categories, another one that contains all available attributes, a n:m mapping table that maps the attributes to the categories and then a table with many columns that contains all the categories as column names. for select/insert query the needed attributes for given part, set others to NULL.

Comment: b) a table for every category, a table for all parts - the most specific subcategory for a given part then references the part. creating a new part involves inserting values to the most specific and all parent tables. that allows searching/filtering at every category-level. What is very unconvincing here is that I didn't find a way to specify generic queries. Is it necessary to specify a query for each category here? An example: one could choose __n-channel mosfets__ one could choose __mosfets__ but one could also choose __transistors__ and so on...
or are ther further options?

Comment: Usually you would take advantage of the specific functionality of your database server.  For example, in MS SQL (and several others) I would implement this as either a sparse table or with indexed XML.  If the number of categories is low, I would consider the "one table per type" model, but not if queries have to traverse multiple tables.  In both cases, you could have a very high number of attributes while still being able to create indexes as needed.  There are a number of NoSQL databases which also handle schemaless queries that could be of use.  Any of the terms above should get you close.

Comment: Also, you can just [buy the functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation), or use a DB which has built in support for attributes and faceted search.  ([Solr comes to mind.](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html))