# SQL database design with some user defined fields

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm developing a database schema to handle collection of data and later, reporting on this data.

After a requirements discussion, it seems that either an entity-attribute-value (EAV) solution, or a flat table solution would be alright - since the data is somewhat sparse but not *highly sparse*.

However, user defined fields will become a must in the future, but I understand that querying and optimizing an RDBMS with EAV tables can become complex.

I've taken a look at the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106335/how-to-design-a-database-for-user-defined-fields), and I was thinking an option similar to **option 1** would be possible. For example, have a number of set fields, then a number of *spare* fields that users can define the labels of.

In terms of reporting, is there any downside in using this approach rather than using EAV?

Comment: In Postgres either use a `hstore` column or a `jsonb`

Answer (score 4):

You will regret EAV, especially when it comes to reporting

1. Make sure you're aware of existing data model patterns before you try anything: [Ready to use database model patterns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831)
2. Familiarize yourself with Table Inheritance: [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)
3. Consider allowing users to modify their own schemas: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html
4. EAV is almost always a really bad idea. If you still need custom fields after trying the above, use a blob type (like JSON or XML) with indexing: http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql . Postgres's binary `jsonb` is fast and allows indexing/querying

Comment: I'll take a more in depth look into serialized LOB, as it does seem a little easier in terms of queryability.

I don't think user modifiable schemas will be ideal, as fields may exist very briefly (e.g. a new field  for a year that may not exist the next year). This makes EAV and JSON type fields more attractive, due to their dynamic nature.

Additionally I've also seen this [EAV paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC346624/), which shows a relatively common use in medical data colleciton.