# Unpivot multiple columns and value

Tags: sql-server

I have a query with period and three columns, which are of different data types.

```
abc: int
def: decimal
hij: int
```

Data for these three columns provides come from different queries.

*Here is the current result*:

```
Period    abc   def   hij
------    ----  ----  ---
2012-01    10   0.00    4
2012-02     5   0.00    5
2012-03     0   2.40    8
```

*I would like to get the following output*:

```
abc 2012-01 10 0.00
abc 2012-02  5 0.00
abc 2012-03  0 0.00
def 2012-01  0 0.00
def 2012-02  0 0.00
def 2012-03  0 2.40
hij 2012-01  4 0.00
hij 2012-02  5 0.00
hij 2012-03  8 0.00
```

I would like to use unpivot but it gives me an error of conflict type.

Comment: Could you provide the queries used to produce the current result, to make it easier to answer your question?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266494/how-to-change-the-information-in-this-table-into-an-easy-to-use-form/10266894#10266894).

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is because you are mixing decimal with int in the UNPIVOT.

It looks like you are wanting to UNPIVOT but then separate `def` back out from the other columns again.

I was able to achieve what appears to be the desired result like this:

```
declare @t table(Period varchar(10), abc int, def decimal(5,2), hij int)
insert into @t values ('2012-01',10,0.00,4)
, ('2012-02',5,0.00,5)
, ('2012-03',0,2.40,8);

with a as (
    select cols, Period, val
    from (select Period, abc=CAST(abc as decimal(5,2)), def, hij=CAST(hij as decimal(5,2)) from @t) p
    UNPIVOT (
        val for cols in (abc, def, hij) 
    ) as unpvt
)
select a.cols
, Period
, abc_hij=case when cols in ('abc','hij') then CAST(val as int) else 0 end
, def=case when cols = ('def') then val else 0.00 end
from a
order by cols, Period
go
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. If this works for you, please check the Accepted checkbox by the solution:)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH c AS (
SELECT  '2012-01' AS Period,    10 AS abc ,  0.00 AS def,    4 AS hij
UNION ALL
SELECT  '2012-02' AS Period,     5 AS abc,   0.00 AS def ,   5 AS hij
UNION ALL
SELECT  '2012-03' AS Period,     0  AS abc,  2.40 AS def,    8 AS hij
)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT cc.title, c.Period,cc.val FROM c
cross apply
(
  VALUES('abc',abc),('def',def),('hij',hij)
) cc (title,val)
) t
ORDER BY t.title
```