# Storing Multiple data type

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I want to store user metadata setting for user. but the metadata value is multiple datatype, can be integer, string, date, or boolean.

So I came with my own solution

```
user(user_id(PK), ...)

meta(
   meta_id (PK)
 , user_id (FK)
 , data_type
 , meta_name
 , ...)

meta_user(
   user_id(FK)
 , meta_id(FK)
 , number_value
 , decimal_value
 , string_value
 , date_value
 , time_value
 , boolean_value)
```

But I'm not sure that's the right way to store multiple data type. I hope some one here can help me share their solution.

UPDATE:
User may have many metadata, and user must first register their metadata.

Comment: user may have many metadata, and user must first register their metadata.

Comment: If you want to implement something like attributes, you need to define names for the attributes. The table `meta_user` itself has no meaning. The only statement you can extract is that user 'A' has a 10.5 as a decimal meta data but what the 10.5 actually means, you cannot extract from your design.

Comment: @alzaimar : yes sure, i store the meta_name, sorry in my question i forget to write it, i just fill with ... in the example

Comment: Are you forced to use a relational database? A schema-less database like MongoDB or even Redis suits your need well.

Comment: @Xiao Jia : currently yes, we don't have any extra time to migrate our system.

Comment: This is colloquially known as the "Dynamic Database", it is a well known (anti) pattern in a RDBMS. Before proceeding I would highly recommend you read _all_ the links on the top answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385/dynamic-database-schema). I would also highly recommend that you reconsider whether you need to do this at all? How many pieces of metadata do you have? Are you going to allow the user to make up their own? Postgre can have _a lot_ of columns in one table.

Comment: Consider using the ANYTYPE-datatype to hold your values. @Ben: Although this is a well known anti-pattern, it is not 'anti' in every aspect. I personally find it usefull when having to store dynamic information which is not used elsewhere within the logic of the database, i.e. it is not used within a query, constraint etc. A collection of user attributes can be such a scenario.

Comment: @alzaimar : PostgresQL doesn't have ANYTYPE or VARIANT datatype.

Comment: @Ben : Thanks Ben, i will read that link. Yes i need because the user can make their own meta.

Answer (score 3):

My contribution to this is:

1. As you should implement names for the metadata, add a `metadefinition` table:

   ```
   meta_definition (metadefinition_ID(PK), name (varchar), datatype)
   ```
2. Then modify your `meta_user` table

   ```
   meta_user (meta_ID (PK), user_ID(FK), metadefinition_ID(FK))
   ```
3. You have 3 choices (A,B,C) or even more...

Variant A: Keep your design of storing the values for all possible datatypes in one single row resulting in a sparse table.

This is the easiest to implement but the ugliest in terms of 'clean design' (my opinion).

Variant B: Use distinct value tables per data type: Instead of having one sparse table `meta_user` you could use 6 tables `meta_number`, `meta_decimal`, `meta_string`. Each table has the form:

```
meta_XXXX (metadata_ID(PK), meta_ID(FK), value)
```

Imho, this is the cleanest design (but a bit complicated to work with).

Variant C: reduce `meta_user` to hold three columns (I renamed it to `meta_values`, as it hold values and not users).

```
meta_values (metavalue_ID(PK), meta_ID(FK), value (varchar))
```

Format all values as string/varchar and stuff them into the `value` column. This is not well designed and a bad idea if you are going to use the values within SQL as you would have to do expensive and complicated casting in order to use the 'real' values.

This is imho the most compact design.

To list all metadata of a specific user, you can use

```
select u.name, 
       md.name as 'AttributeName',
       md.DataType
  from user u 
       join meta_user mu on u.user_ID = mu.userID
       join meta_definition md on md.metadefinition_ID = mu. metadefinition_ID
```

selecting the values for a given user would be
Variant A:
    select u.name, 
           md.name as 'AttributeName',
           mv.*  -- show all different data types
      from user u 
           join meta_user mu on u.user_ID = mu.userID
           join meta_definition md on md.metadefinition_ID = mu. metadefinition_ID
           join meta_value mv on mv.meta_ID = mu.metaID

Disadvantage: When new datatypes are available, you would have to add a column, recompile the query and change your software as well.

```
select u.name, 
       md.name as 'AttributeName',
       mnum.value as NumericValue,
       mdec.value as DecimalValue
...
  from user u 
       join meta_user mu on u.user_ID = mu.userID
       join meta_definition md on md.metadefinition_ID = mu. metadefinition_ID
       left join meta_numeric mnum on mnum.meta_ID = mu.metaID
       left join meta_decimal mdec on mdec.meta_ID = mu.metaID
...
```

Disadvantage: Slow if many users and attributes are being stored. Needs a new table when a new datatype is being introduced.

Variant C:

```
select u.name, 
       md.name as 'AttributeName',
       md.DataType -- client needs this to convert to original datatype
       mv.value    -- appears formatted as string
  from user u 
       join meta_user mu on u.user_ID = mu.userID
       join meta_definition md on md.metadefinition_ID = mu. metadefinition_ID
       join meta_value mv on mv.meta_ID = mu.metaID
```

Advantage: Don't have to change the query in case new datatypes are being introduced.

Comment: So, you're advocating _more_ joins or storing everything as a character? Imagine that the OP wants to return 20 pieces of metadata on one user. How many joins will that be? For variant B how do you even know which table to join on? I think you'd have to join on the lot... Now assume that the OP wants everything it it's original data-type. How do you go about converting it?

Comment: One row per value. Makes it easy to assign an out-of-the-box editor for this data structure (property editor, vertical grid, you name it, it's available). For 'B' it depends on the datatype, doesn't it? For 'C' you'll have to convert it TO varchar prior to store it and FROM varchar in order to use it, right?

Comment: @alzaimar : Thanks for you answer, but i still don't get the point why i must create many table for different datatype.

Comment: @Ahmad: You don't have to, but if you do so, you have a clean design with minimum redundancy. I personally prefer variant C: It is very easy to implement, easy to maintain and extremely easy to use in the front end. In any case: It is not a superduper solution, but I could not find anything as flexible and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Every data type in PostgreSQL can be cast to `text`, which is therefore the natural common ground for data or variable type.

I suggest you have a look at the additional module [**hstore**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html). I quote the manual:

> This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of
>   key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. This can be useful
>   in various scenarios, such as rows with many attributes that are
>   rarely examined, or semi-structured data. Keys and values are simply
>   text strings.

That's a fast, proven, versatile solution and easy to extend for more attributes.

In addition you could have a table where you register meta-data (like data type and more)  for each attribute. You could use this meta-data to check whether the attribute can be cast to its attached type (and passes additional tests stored in the meta-table) in a *trigger* on `INSERT OR UPDATE` to maintain integrity.

Be aware that many standard-features of the RDBMS are not easily available for such a storage regime. Basically you run into most of the problems you have with an **EAV** model ("entity-attribute-value"). You can find very good advice for that under [this related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

Comment: Hi Erwin, can you kindly please provide an example :) Thanks before

Comment: @Ahmad: [There is an example section in the manual for hstore.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#AEN140101)