# Inserting data into a MySql table which changes dynamically through Java

Tags: java, mysql

Can you help me with my problem of inserting rows to a table whose columns/ fields change dynamically. I have a table named schedule, in which depending the fields increase or decrease dynamically. 
My requirement is to insert data into this table. The problem is that, I am unsure of how many fields are there, because, it increases or decreases dynamically.

My idea: I have used ResultSetMetaData to dynamically know the field names. With this, I can use the insert query which wil be like:

```
ResultSet res = stat.executeUpdate("insert into scheduletab (name,date,shift,'"+col_name[i]+"') values (....., ...., .....)");
```

The problem here is that how will I initialize or specify the value of "i" ?

My code is :

Note: b34 is the button to submit.

```
if (e.getSource() == b34)
{
    String[] col_name = new String[25];
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:mysql://localhost/nursedb", "root", "123456");
        try
        {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM scheduletab");
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int col = md.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println("Number of Column : " + col);
            System.out.println("Columns Name: ");
            for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++)
            {
                col_name[i] = md.getColumnName(i);
                System.out.println(col_name[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
        }

        // Start Inserting data into Schedule Tab by specifying the
        // column names.
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        // ResultSet res =
        // stat.executeUpdate("insert into scheduletab (name,date,shift,'"values();
        // End Inserting data into Schedule Tab by specifying the column
        // names.

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make use of StringBuilder and build the query according to your need. I will also suggest that make your connection in some other class than putting everything into some button listener.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I hope my answer will help resolve your issue. Let me know if you have any problems while doing this.

Comment: Are you saying that the database *schema* is modified while the application is running?

Comment: @Dave Thats what his sql query is suggesting

Comment: @smit: if so, it's a horrible idea. There needs to be some correspondence between the data and the schema; if the schema changes, the application will have no way to know what the changes mean.

Comment: @Dave I agree its terrible design. Moreover he is making DB connection inside some listener which is another design issue. But we really dont know what are his intention of doing this. He could have good reason for doing this otherwise everything looks straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

If your database schema is changing dynamically, you are almost certainly going down a bad path.

Check out [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385/dynamic-database-schema) for some cautionary advice.