# how to move mails into separate folders

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a gmail like mail application. In that I have created sign up sign in and creating mails and displaying the inbox with received mails. To display inbox I folloed the following procedure.
First I created a database called getdata and stored the mails of all users in that database.
When ever a user logs into his account I used the following code to display his mails from the whole database

```
public static DataSet Get_Data_id(string mailid, int Sno)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from AddData where Sno='" + Sno + "' and EmailID='" + mailid + "'";
    ds = SQLHelper.ExecuteAdapter(cmd, CommandType.Text, cmd.CommandText);
    return ds;
}
```

I have given every user a serial number. Using serial number and his mail id I filled his/her inbox. Now the thing is I need to move those messages into separate folder
I have a check box for every mail in inbox and by clicking on that a drop down window appears just like in gmail. But I'm getting a doubt like do I need to move all mails into separate database..? In that case I need a plenty of databases like one database for one folder. And there is also another problem like every user will have different folder names. How to overcome it. How should I design the db and how to move the mails into separate folders for each user  ?

Comment: The answer of @Erno de Weerd is the answer that you should follow here, dynamic database approach is way too beyond the limits of what you are trying to achive here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy gmail, do not make folders, make tags.

Create a table that will contain tags per user (tagid, userid, tagname)

Create a table that will contain the relation between emails and tags (emailid, tagid)

This way an email can have several tags and a tag can contain multiple emails.

It is also possible to retrieve all tags by user.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create db dynamically.This is called "Dynamic DB"
check this post it may help:

[Dynamic Database Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385/dynamic-database-schema)