# dynamic text field in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have created a table. There are dynamic text field for each row to fill the information. I know how to create and dynamic text field. But i am having a doubt in how to add them into database by clicking a submit button. In this picture you can get the idea. By clicking that add link we can add dynamic text field as we need. when i click submit all data are saved into same name(ex: saving in tr).[image: screenshot.]

Comment: Use an array in the `name` attribute of your fields. That way all data will be send to your server. No matter how many fields you add dynamicly: Example: `name="mydata[]"`

Comment: yhh but i have to get like name by name. for example if row 1 have dynamic field then it save row 1's name. row 2 will save in row's name. but here row1, row 2 both save in row 1's name.  i couldn't define those dynamic field to each row. so now i am trying that

Answer (score 1):

Your field name should be  array type.

**Example [Row 1]**

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<select name="types[]">
    <option>....</option>
    <option>....</option>
</select>
```

**Example [Row 2]**

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<select name="types[]">
    <option>....</option>
    <option>....</option>
</select>
```

> **Note :** Follow above code for every rows.

**After submitting form data, `PHP` array looks like.**

```
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
    array(2) {
     [0]=>"Name 1"
     [1]=>"Name 2"
    }
  ["types"]=>
    array(2) {
     [0]=>"Type 1"
     [1]=>"Type 2"
    }
}
```

Use `PHP` loop and separate every rows for saving data to your database.

Comment: thank you for your reply but the think is those rows also dynamic. i am getting that name from database. if database have 2 name then it will be two row.  i am having a loop also but still i couldn't define those dynamic field to each row. so now i am trying that

Comment: But, You can put dynamic field in `name="{DYNAMIC_NAME_HERE}"` from database. @k.MK28

Comment: i mean name from data base is---- in that pic there are some name like tr, uit those are from database.

Comment: But in your question those are not `name`, Those are `value`  @k.MK28

Comment: yh sorry those values are from database

Comment: So, You can put those `value` in `input` fields like as `value="<?php echo $variable ?>"` using loop @k.MK28

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129333/discussion-between-k-mk28-and-sumon-sarker).

Answer (score 1):

you should use a software like phpmyadmin and create a database there. once created, name a table for example 'mytable' and add the necessary columns corresponding to your data. so when you press the submit button, it should take action on a separate php file which would use POST method to take the values and contain them in a variable. once in a variable create an sql statement like this one "INSERT INTO mytable .............. " with ....... being your values. its a long process though, you should use a website to learn how to insert data into your database

Comment: thank you for your reply i know those things , i couldn't handle with dynamic text fields, the think is those rows also dynamic. i am getting that name from database. if database have 2 name then it will be two row.  i am having a loop also but still i couldn't define those dynamic field to each row. so now i am trying that

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385/dynamic-database-schema)

Comment: get help from the link above